# Automatic React build for Django server

Tags: django, reactjs, build

I know there is probably a simple solution to this but I was not able to find anything. I am using VSCode and have a front end in React and backend in Django, but currently, whenever I make a change in the front end it seems like I need to rebuild everything for the changes to appear in the Django server. Is there any way I can automate this so I don't need to build every small change I make?

Comment: Is auto-reload is working?

Comment: If I'm just running react it will auto reload but not with the Django server